# change images randomly in HTML on Click on button

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

i would like to change images randomaly on mouse click.
i found this option:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
function banner() { } ; b = new banner() ; n = 0
b[n++]= "<A HREF='index.html'><IMG SRC='images/pic1.jpg'></A>"
b[n++]= "<A HREF='index.html'><IMG SRC='images/pic2.jpg'></A>"
b[n++]= "<A HREF='index.html'><IMG SRC='images/pic3.jpg'></A>"
b[n++]= "<A HREF='index.html'><IMG SRC='images/pic4.jpg'></A>"
i=Math.floor(Math.random() * n) ; 
document.write( b[i] )
</SCRIPT>
```

This option work perfectly, but i need that "pic1" will always be the first picture ( also when refresh the page) and also that "pic1" will not be one of the other pictures that change randomaly on mouse click.

thank you,
aviv

Comment: Just take pic1 out of the script and add it to the HTML of the page; only call the script on click and not on page load.

Comment: Thank you for the response. i don't really know javescript.
I just want to embeded the right code in my website.
I will appricate it if you can explain me how to call the script on click and not on page load.

Comment: I figure it out. I understood how to call the script only on click.
Thank you, aviv

Answer (score 0):

I literally just did this for a project where the first slide is always the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/4TvVv/2/ Keep hitting Change Order n to see second/third images change.

```
<button class="randomize">Change Order!</button>

<ul>
    <li class="slide active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
    </li>
    <li class="slide active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" />
    </li>
    <li class="slide active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/450x250" />
    </li>                
</ul>


$(document).ready(function() {
    // Randomize slides except first
    $('.randomize').click(function(e) {
        $('ul').each(function(){
            var $ul = $(this);
            var $liArr = $ul.children('li:not(:first)');

            // sort array of list items in current ul randomly
            $liArr.sort(function(a,b){
                var temp = parseInt( Math.random()*10 );
                var isOddOrEven = temp%2;
                var isPosOrNeg = temp>5 ? 1 : -1;
                return( isOddOrEven*isPosOrNeg );
            })
            // append list items to ul
            .appendTo($ul);            
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: btw, I grabbed most of this from somewhere on SO, but I can't find the questions.

Comment: Do you have jQuery loading on your page? And what anchor/button is supposed to randomize the order?

Comment: Im just trying to solve this problem. this is the only thing on the website for now. no jQuery loading on my page.

Comment: I just want to say that i don't really know jQuery. i know just to embeded it in the code.

Comment: I updated my answer, it's literally copy/paste. Make sure to wrap the javascript in a script tag if you're loading it inline.

Comment: Hi, i tried it, but iT didn't work for me.
I think that i figure it out. you can see the result in:
www.avivumflat.com

the shirt change to a diffrent random color on every click and when im re-enter or re-fresh the site, the shirt is white.

Thank you very much, aviv